# How can I apply chef configuration without registering the node in the server?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, chef-infra

I am programming some short-lived EC2 instances. They will exist for only a few hours to do a job every now and again but will require a very large EBS volume; to keep it around all the time would cost hundreds of dollars a month. Because EBS volumes are pro-rated, I can just allocate this volume when I need it and discard it after the job is complete so the cost will not be all that high (EBS volumes are billed hourly after all).

Unfortunately the elastic file store is not yet available in my region, and it's also in a preview mode at the moment so probably not suitable for production use yet anyway.

Anyway, that's really just background. What I'd like to do is is have my instance automatically configure itself when it is started using user data. I would like it to download a script from an S3 repository that instructs it to install chef-client and execute a chef-client run that will set up the node. It will then run another command which will kick off the job. Once that's complete, the AWS Data Pipeline will automatically terminate the instance.

The one point I don't like about the above is that when I register the node, the node will be registered in my Chef server. I'd like to just download the configuration for a specified role without actually registering anything. I'll never need to run the configuration again because the instance will be gone in a couple of hours once the job is complete.

I could of course script the entire setup and execution of the above using shell scripts but I'd rather tie it in with all the Chef infrastructure we've already built, which is integrated with our CI server and is fully source-controlled and so on.

Comment: Have you heard about chef-client's [local mode aka chef-zero](https://www.chef.io/blog/2013/10/31/chef-client-z-from-zero-to-chef-in-8-5-seconds/)?

Comment: Yes - I use that for development, but I believe I would somehow have to have the entire chef repository on the local machine. I guess I could do a git clone or output the repository as a build artifact on the build server.

Comment: You could let Berkshelf pull down the cookbooks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `chef-provisioning` and/or `knife-zero`.

They start a `chef-zero` in-memory server locally, then bootstrap a node which connects through the SSH connection back to your local `chef-zero` server. After the converge, the connection is shut down. It's much like rsync+chef-solo but on steroids.

See:

- https://github.com/higanworks/knife-zero
- https://github.com/chef/chef-provisioning
- https://github.com/chef/chef-provisioning-aws